# Odoo: How to select custom fields using menu id

Tags: odoo-8

I have made some custom fields into my_purchase_custom.py class like as below.

> - Custom A
> - Custom B
> - Custom C
> - etc.

Now, there are two menu items in **purchase.order** model

> 1. Requests for Quotations **[menu_id=314]**
> 2. Purchase Orders **[menu_id=315]**

What I want to do is I want to put field Custom A into **menu_id=314** and fields Custom B and Custom C into **menu_id=315**

Please help in this regards how to change my .xml file. I went through this link: https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/help-1/question/hide-menu-for-existing-group-18704 but couldnot understand properly. An example code snippet will be good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do the following way some things like this.

**Add the Below code  in your .py File**
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

```
class purchase_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit ="purchase.order"
    _columns = {
        'custom_a': fields.char('Custom A'),
        'custom_b': fields.char('Custom B'),
        'custom_b': fields.char('Custom C'),
    }
```

**Add the Below code  in your .xml File**

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="r3x_inherit_purchase_ord">
    <field name="name">Purchase Order Inherit Form</field>
    <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <xpath expr="//field[@name='pricelist_id']" position="after">
            <field name="custom_a  attrs={'invisible':[('state','!=','draft')]}/>
            <field name="custom_b attrs={'invisible':[('state','=','draft')]} />
            <field name="custom_c attrs={'invisible':[('state','=','draft')]}/ />
        </xpath>

    </field>
</record>
```

please you can also set the path of the **openerp**.py file and add the entry in your .py file in **init**.py file.

check with the upgrade the module and restart the server and check the effect on purchase order form view.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: this worked !! As I can understand this is done from the state of the purchase. Can you please tell, if same thing could be done while making the report ?

Comment: No thing else just you can add your customized fields from the report same as you can add as the purchase order fields because above three costomized fileds are become a part of purchase order

Comment: yep that is right.. kind of figured it out later .. thanks though

Comment: Hello ! Can you please check this question if possible ? https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/messages-and-communication-history-customization-91902

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an action to your menuitem and load the specific views that you want. For instance:

```xml
<record id="action_sale_order_view" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Quotations</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">sale.order</field>            
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form,calendar,graph</field>
    <field name="domain">[('field_name','=',False)]</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
      <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
        Click to define a new quotation.
      </p>
    </field>             
</record> 

<record id="view_act_object_tree" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="sale.view_quotation_tree" />
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_sale_order_view" />
</record>

<record id="view_act_object_form" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="sale.view_order_form" />
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_sale_order_view" />         
</record>       

<record id="view_act_object_calendar" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field name="view_mode">calendar</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="sale.view_sale_order_calendar" />
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_sale_order_view" />
</record>   

<record id="view_act_object_graph" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
    <field name="view_mode">graph</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="sale.view_sale_order_graph" />
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_sale_order_view" />
</record> 

<menuitem id="main_sale_order_view" 
          name="Quotations" 
          parent="base.menu_sales" 
          sequence="4" 
          action="action_sale_order_view" />
```

And you can show or hide the elements that you wish in your custom views. Is that what you are looking for?